# Integer from tuple, divided, yields integer instead of float?

Tags: python

In the code below,

```
abc = (1,2,3)
a = abc[0]
b = abc[1]
c = abc[2]

print('%d, %d, %d' %(a,b,c)) # gives 1,2,3 as expected

a /= 3
b /= 3
c /= 3

print('%d, %d, %d' %(a,b,c)) # gives 0,0,1... which is NOT expected
```

I'm trying, however, to have `a, b, c` be `0.333, 0.6666, 1` respectively.

This problem persists even when I:

- divide by 3.0
- use a stupid abc = tuple([i/3.0 for i in abc]) workaround and then try to list all the elements again as above
- even when I cast everything into a float like:

  ```
  a = float(float(a)/float(3.0)) # still returns 0
  ```

I'm even using python 3, so an int/int division should return a float regardless.

Comment: Silly Noob, `%d` is for integers. (Sorry, I couldn't resist with your username being what it was.)

Comment: python 3. But even if I were using 2, I have cast literally all the things to float, and even then things didn't work.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me -_-

You are absolutely correct. Changed it to a %s and hey presto, floats. 

Looks like my actual problem lies somewhere else lol

Thanks AOW!

Comment: `%d` = print as integers, `%f` = print as floats, `%s` = print as strings; basically it is returning a float and you're just not familiar with the format specifiers you're using to display it. No problem at all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `print` statements say to display the values as integers (`%d`); try using `%f` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `%d` so the output is printed as ints/decimal just use print:

```
print(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use %f inside print statement

```
print('%f, %f, %f', %(a,b,c))
```